# 2012 r2 server DNS A records Host (A) record (DNS) updated with wrong IP address

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

we're using 2012 r2 server DNS A records Host (A) record (DNS) updated with wrong IP address in domain systems eg: hoskname like a b c d.... ip address like a is 1 b is 2 c is 3 and d is 2 like that shwoing in DNS record but all hostname systems are live in network acutal ip address is different how to solve it ? where we're missing the configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check dns resolving status by command "nslookup domain name" in any windows PC's connected in same LAN and must use same primary dns ip address must be configured in PC's network adapter properties.

If your found dns is resolving to wrong ip then create correct A record accordingly with correct ip

Comment: thanks for reply but we have primary DNS as will as secondary DNS server also so it's shwoing both the server only